# replace mouseover trigger with time delay after load

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have the following code that triggers smoke transition effect on mouseover. I would like the animation to trigger after page load after a 20 second delay and get rid of the mouse trigger. Any help would be appreciated.

```
var headingLetter = heading.find('span')

headingLetter.on('mouseover', function(){
    $(this).removeClass('back').addClass('active')
})

headingLetter.on('animationend webkitAnimationEnd oAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd', function(e){
    if ( $(e.target).hasClass('active')  ){
        $(this).removeClass('active').addClass('back')
    }else{
        $(this).removeClass('back')
    }
```

Comment: Have you looked into `setTimeout()` inside a document ready function?

Answer (score 0):

For the delay, `setTimeout()` is what you need. Check out the examples provided here
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp